# Where to get an updated SVG version of Stack Overflow logo?

Tags: discussion, logo

Where do I get an SVG version of the updated Stack Overflow logo?

There is [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55001/where-can-i-get-a-vector-stack-overflow-logo), but I realized it uses the old logo. I think it would be a simple color change so I attempted to do the color change, but it isn't exactly the same.

```css
rect, path {
  fill-opacity:1;
  stroke:none;
}

.bottom {
  fill: #BCBBBC;
}

.orange-rect {
  fill: #F38023;
}
```

```html
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="64"
   height="64"
   id="stackoverflow-icon">
  <g>
    <path
       d="m 9.3049611,36.847632 4.4013079,0.04316 -0.153442,19.598393 29.291259,0 0,-19.527506 4.637782,0 0,24.287331 -38.2006795,0 0.023777,-24.401371 z"
       class="bottom"/>
    <rect
       width="22.944817"
       height="4.881876"
       x="16.481951"
       y="48.434078"
       class="orange-rect" />
    <rect
       width="23.066864"
       height="5.0039229"
       x="20.749949"
       y="37.830307"
       transform="matrix(0.9953749,0.09606666,-0.09606666,0.9953749,0,0)"
       class="orange-rect" />
    <rect
       width="23.066864"
       height="5.0039229"
       x="26.472515"
       y="23.401554"
       transform="matrix(0.96240291,0.27162592,-0.27162592,0.96240291,0,0)"
       class="orange-rect" />
    <rect
       width="23.066864"
       height="5.0039229"
       x="30.528769"
       y="3.1535864"
       transform="matrix(0.85597805,0.51701216,-0.51701216,0.85597805,0,0)"
       class="orange-rect" />
    <rect
       width="23.066864"
       height="5.0039229"
       x="27.191883"
       y="-24.475019"
       transform="matrix(0.58242689,0.81288309,-0.81288309,0.58242689,0,0)"
       class="orange-rect" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The new logo has one fewer bar (which I removed), but it seems the bars are positioned a little differently and the bottom bracket is fatter(?). Is there an official SVG version to reference for logos since the [official icons on the logos page only provides PNG](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos) and most of the SVG versions I see circling around use the old logo?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Stack Exchange [does provide their full logos in EPS vector format](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos), in addition to the PNG icons. An EPS can be converted to SVG. Here are some conversions I have done, with some clean-up to remove the excess markup that was auto-generated.

##Full Logo:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="118px">
<path fill="#222426" d="M135.874,72.909l-6.833-0.605c-5.363-0.432-7.439-2.595-7.439-6.228c0-4.324,3.286-7.006,9.515-7.006
    c4.412,0,8.304,1.038,11.331,3.373l4.066-4.065c-3.807-3.113-9.256-4.583-15.31-4.583c-9.083,0-15.657,4.671-15.657,12.455
    c0,7.006,4.412,10.726,12.716,11.418l7.006,0.605c4.93,0.433,7.093,2.509,7.093,6.228c0,5.017-4.325,7.526-11.332,7.526
    c-5.276,0-9.861-1.385-13.235-4.931l-4.152,4.153c4.671,4.498,10.294,6.141,17.473,6.141c10.293,0,17.299-4.758,17.299-12.974
    C148.416,76.456,143.313,73.602,135.874,72.909z M189.132,53.794c-6.828,0-11.129,1.347-14.898,6.118
    c-0.051,0.065,4.086,4.088,4.086,4.088c2.508-3.546,5.276-4.844,10.726-4.844c7.785,0,10.899,3.114,10.899,9.341v4.065h-12.802
    c-9.515,0-14.705,4.845-14.705,12.283c0,3.373,1.124,6.573,3.2,8.65c2.682,2.768,6.142,3.892,12.024,3.892
    c5.709,0,8.822-1.124,12.283-4.585v4.065h6.228V67.979C206.171,58.723,200.549,53.794,189.132,53.794z M199.944,81.818
    c0,3.548-0.692,5.969-2.163,7.353c-2.681,2.595-5.881,2.855-9.515,2.855c-6.747,0-9.774-2.336-9.774-7.267
    c0-4.929,3.114-7.524,9.515-7.524h11.937V81.818z M230.564,59.33c4.065,0,6.574,1.21,9.774,4.757c0,0,4.17-4.052,4.135-4.089
    c-4.367-4.671-8.074-6.203-13.91-6.203c-10.726,0-18.857,7.266-18.857,21.798c0,14.531,8.131,21.798,18.857,21.798
    c5.882,0,9.601-1.558,14.013-6.314l-4.239-4.065c-3.2,3.546-5.709,4.844-9.774,4.844c-4.152,0-7.612-1.644-9.86-4.844
    c-1.99-2.768-2.768-6.055-2.768-11.418c0-5.363,0.778-8.65,2.768-11.418C222.952,60.972,226.412,59.33,230.564,59.33z
     M283.904,54.25h-7.764l-19.297,18.786l0.03-37.753h-6.228V96.87h6.228l-0.03-15.533l7.555-7.582l14.274,23.114h7.698
    l-17.657-27.428L283.904,54.25z M313.164,52.033c-6.552,0-10.977,2.553-13.7,5.446c-3.999,4.17-5.021,9.191-5.021,17.19
    c0,8.083,1.022,13.104,5.021,17.274c2.723,2.893,7.148,5.446,13.7,5.446c6.552,0,11.062-2.553,13.785-5.446
    c3.999-4.17,5.021-9.191,5.021-17.274c0-7.999-1.022-13.02-5.021-17.19C324.226,54.586,319.716,52.033,313.164,52.033z
     M318.355,85.475c-1.276,1.276-2.979,1.957-5.191,1.957s-3.829-0.681-5.105-1.957c-2.298-2.297-2.553-6.212-2.553-10.806
    c0-4.596,0.255-8.425,2.553-10.722c1.276-1.276,2.893-1.957,5.105-1.957s3.915,0.681,5.191,1.957
    c2.297,2.297,2.553,6.126,2.553,10.722C320.908,79.264,320.652,83.179,318.355,85.475z M361.427,52.544l-8.935,27.401l-9.021-27.401
    h-11.658l16.338,44.334h8.68l16.253-44.334H361.427z M391.904,52.033c-11.488,0-19.316,8.169-19.316,22.636
    c0,17.955,10.041,22.72,20.508,22.72c7.999,0,12.339-2.468,16.849-6.979l-6.722-6.552c-2.809,2.809-5.191,4.17-10.042,4.17
    c-6.212,0-9.7-4.17-9.7-9.87h27.741v-4.935C411.221,61.054,404.242,52.033,391.904,52.033z M383.48,70.584
    c0.084-1.958,0.341-3.148,1.022-4.765c1.191-2.639,3.659-4.595,7.402-4.595c3.745,0,6.213,1.956,7.404,4.595
    c0.681,1.617,0.936,2.807,1.022,4.765H383.48z M427.538,56.798v-4.254h-10.808v44.334h11.062v-26.72
    c0-5.616,3.745-8.169,7.149-8.169c2.723,0,4.134,0.905,5.837,2.607l8.373-8.393c-3.064-3.064-6.127-4.17-10.467-4.17
    C433.92,52.033,429.665,54.246,427.538,56.798z M452.583,47.922v48.91h11.063V61.878h8.169v-8.424h-8.169v-4.851
    c0-2.553,1.276-3.999,3.914-3.999h4.256v-9.36h-6.298C456.497,35.244,452.583,41.626,452.583,47.922z M517.359,52.033
    c-6.552,0-10.977,2.553-13.7,5.446c-3.999,4.17-5.021,9.191-5.021,17.19c0,8.083,1.022,13.104,5.021,17.274
    c2.723,2.893,7.147,5.446,13.7,5.446c6.552,0,11.062-2.553,13.785-5.446c3.999-4.17,5.021-9.191,5.021-17.274
    c0-7.999-1.022-13.02-5.021-17.19C528.421,54.586,523.911,52.033,517.359,52.033z M522.55,85.475
    c-1.276,1.276-2.979,1.957-5.191,1.957c-2.212,0-3.829-0.681-5.106-1.957c-2.298-2.297-2.553-6.212-2.553-10.806
    c0-4.596,0.255-8.425,2.553-10.722c1.276-1.276,2.893-1.957,5.106-1.957c2.212,0,3.915,0.681,5.191,1.957
    c2.297,2.297,2.553,6.126,2.553,10.722C525.103,79.264,524.847,83.179,522.55,85.475z M588.428,52.544l-7.149,27.401l-9.105-27.401
    h-8.083l-9.021,27.401l-7.147-27.401h-11.743l13.615,44.334h9.105l9.275-27.826l9.275,27.826h9.105l13.531-44.334H588.428z
     M488.137,83.518V35.244h-11.062v48.955c0,6.297,3.829,12.679,12.934,12.679h6.296v-9.361h-4.254
    C489.243,87.517,488.137,86.156,488.137,83.518z M165.686,61.007l5.758-5.758h-11.791V41.251h-6.228v44.2
    c0,6.314,3.633,11.418,10.899,11.418h4.412v-5.363h-3.287c-3.979,0-5.796-2.336-5.796-6.228V61.007H165.686z" />
<polygon fill="#BCBBBB" points="84.072,107.351 84.072,75.8 94.588,75.8 94.588,117.869 0,117.869 0,75.8 10.516,75.8 
    10.516,107.351 " />
<path fill="#F48024" d="M22.089,72.898l51.458,10.815l2.163-10.292L24.252,62.606L22.089,72.898z M28.897,48.259l47.666,22.199
    l4.44-9.533L33.337,38.726L28.897,48.259z M42.088,24.874l40.405,33.65l6.73-8.081l-40.405-33.65L42.088,24.874z M68.171,0
    l-8.438,6.276l31.381,42.191l8.438-6.276L68.171,0z M21.044,96.833l52.582,0V86.316l-52.582,0V96.833z" />
</svg>
```

##Just Icon:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="118px">
<polygon fill="#BCBBBB" points="84.072,107.351 84.072,75.8 94.588,75.8 94.588,117.869 0,117.869 0,75.8 10.516,75.8 
    10.516,107.351 " />
<path fill="#F48024" d="M22.089,72.898l51.458,10.815l2.163-10.292L24.252,62.606L22.089,72.898z M28.897,48.259l47.666,22.199
    l4.44-9.533L33.337,38.726L28.897,48.259z M42.088,24.874l40.405,33.65l6.73-8.081l-40.405-33.65L42.088,24.874z M68.171,0
    l-8.438,6.276l31.381,42.191l8.438-6.276L68.171,0z M21.044,96.833l52.582,0V86.316l-52.582,0V96.833z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's the URL of the sprite that contains the logo in StackOverflow website:

http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg

Open it with a web browser, open the console, go to Elements.

You will see a node with the StackOverflow logo, move it by drag and drop at top of the hierarchy, remove other nodes and set `viewBox` to :

```
-135 22 190 38
```

height to `38px` and width to `190px`.

Right-click on the SVG node, then Copy > Copy outerHTML.

That's it, you will get this :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="190px" height="38px" viewBox="-135 22 190 38" enable-background="new -135 0 240 500" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <path fill="#222426" d="M-92.2,45.4l-2.2-0.2c-1.7-0.1-2.3-0.8-2.3-2c0-1.4,1-2.2,3-2.2c1.4,0,2.6,0.3,3.6,1.1l1.3-1.3    c-1.2-1-2.9-1.4-4.8-1.4c-2.9,0-4.9,1.5-4.9,3.9c0,2.2,1.4,3.4,4,3.6l2.2,0.2c1.6,0.1,2.2,0.8,2.2,2c0,1.6-1.4,2.4-3.6,2.4    c-1.7,0-3.1-0.4-4.2-1.6l-1.3,1.3c1.5,1.4,3.2,1.9,5.5,1.9c3.2,0,5.5-1.5,5.5-4.1C-88.2,46.5-89.8,45.6-92.2,45.4z M-75.4,39.3    c-2.2,0-3.5,0.4-4.7,1.9l1.3,1.3c0.8-1.1,1.7-1.5,3.4-1.5c2.5,0,3.4,1,3.4,2.9v1.3h-4c-3,0-4.6,1.5-4.6,3.9c0,1.1,0.4,2.1,1,2.7    c0.8,0.9,1.9,1.2,3.8,1.2c1.8,0,2.8-0.4,3.9-1.4v1.3h2v-9.1C-70,40.9-71.8,39.3-75.4,39.3z M-72,48.2c0,1.1-0.2,1.9-0.7,2.3    c-0.8,0.8-1.9,0.9-3,0.9c-2.1,0-3.1-0.7-3.1-2.3s1-2.4,3-2.4h3.8C-72,46.7-72,48.2-72,48.2z M-62.3,41.1c1.3,0,2.1,0.4,3.1,1.5    l1.3-1.3c-1.4-1.5-2.5-2-4.4-2c-3.4,0-5.9,2.3-5.9,6.9s2.6,6.9,5.9,6.9c1.9,0,3-0.5,4.4-2l-1.3-1.3c-1,1.1-1.8,1.5-3.1,1.5    s-2.4-0.5-3.1-1.5c-0.6-0.9-0.9-1.9-0.9-3.6c0-1.7,0.2-2.7,0.9-3.6C-64.7,41.6-63.6,41.1-62.3,41.1z M-45.5,39.5h-2.4l-6.1,5.9    V33.5h-2v19.4h2V48l2.4-2.4l4.5,7.3h2.4l-5.6-8.6L-45.5,39.5z M-36.3,38.8c-2.1,0-3.5,0.8-4.3,1.7c-1.3,1.3-1.6,2.9-1.6,5.4    s0.3,4.1,1.6,5.4c0.9,0.9,2.3,1.7,4.3,1.7c2.1,0,3.5-0.8,4.3-1.7c1.3-1.3,1.6-2.9,1.6-5.4s-0.3-4.1-1.6-5.4    C-32.8,39.6-34.2,38.8-36.3,38.8z M-34.6,49.3c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.6,0.6s-1.2-0.2-1.6-0.6c-0.7-0.7-0.8-2-0.8-3.4s0.1-2.7,0.8-3.4    c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.6-0.6s1.2,0.2,1.6,0.6c0.7,0.7,0.8,1.9,0.8,3.4C-33.8,47.4-33.9,48.6-34.6,49.3z M-21,38.9l-2.8,8.6l-2.8-8.6    h-3.7l5.2,14h2.7l5.1-14C-17.3,38.9-21,38.9-21,38.9z M-11.4,38.8c-3.6,0-6.1,2.6-6.1,7.1c0,5.7,3.2,7.2,6.5,7.2    c2.5,0,3.9-0.8,5.3-2.2l-2.1-2.1c-0.9,0.9-1.6,1.3-3.2,1.3c-2,0-3.1-1.3-3.1-3.1h8.7v-1.6C-5.3,41.6-7.5,38.8-11.4,38.8z     M-14.1,44.6c0-0.6,0.1-1,0.3-1.5c0.4-0.8,1.2-1.4,2.3-1.4c1.2,0,2,0.6,2.3,1.4c0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9,0.3,1.5H-14.1z M-0.2,40.3V39    h-3.4v14h3.5v-8.4c0-1.8,1.2-2.6,2.3-2.6c0.9,0,1.3,0.3,1.8,0.8l2.6-2.6c-1-1-1.9-1.3-3.3-1.3C1.8,38.8,0.5,39.5-0.2,40.3z     M7.7,37.5v15.4h3.5v-11h2.6v-2.7h-2.6v-1.5c0-0.8,0.4-1.3,1.2-1.3h1.3v-3h-2C8.9,33.5,7.7,35.5,7.7,37.5z M28.1,38.8    c-2.1,0-3.5,0.8-4.3,1.7c-1.3,1.3-1.6,2.9-1.6,5.4s0.3,4.1,1.6,5.4c0.9,0.9,2.3,1.7,4.3,1.7c2.1,0,3.5-0.8,4.3-1.7    c1.3-1.3,1.6-2.9,1.6-5.4s-0.3-4.1-1.6-5.4C31.6,39.6,30.2,38.8,28.1,38.8z M29.8,49.3c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.6,0.6s-1.2-0.2-1.6-0.6    c-0.7-0.7-0.8-2-0.8-3.4s0.1-2.7,0.8-3.4c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.6-0.6s1.2,0.2,1.6,0.6c0.7,0.7,0.8,1.9,0.8,3.4    C30.6,47.4,30.5,48.6,29.8,49.3z M50.5,38.9l-2.3,8.6l-2.9-8.6h-2.5L40,47.6L37.7,39H34l4.3,14h2.9l2.9-8.8L47,53h3l4.3-14    L50.5,38.9L50.5,38.9z M18.9,48.7V33.5h-3.5v15.4c0,2,1.2,4,4.1,4h2v-3h-1.3C19.3,50,18.9,49.5,18.9,48.7z M-82.8,41.6l1.8-1.8    h-3.7v-4.4h-2v13.9c0,2,1.1,3.6,3.4,3.6h1.4v-1.7h-1c-1.3,0-1.8-0.7-1.8-2v-7.7h1.9V41.6z"/>
        <polygon fill="#BCBBBB" points="-108.5,56.2 -108.5,46.3 -105.2,46.3 -105.2,59.5 -135,59.5 -135,46.3 -131.7,46.3 -131.7,56.2       "/>
        <path fill="#F48024" d="M-128,45.4l16.2,3.4l0.7-3.2l-16.2-3.4L-128,45.4z M-125.9,37.6l15,7l1.4-3l-15-7L-125.9,37.6z     M-121.7,30.2l12.7,10.6l2.1-2.5l-12.7-10.6L-121.7,30.2z M-113.5,22.4l-2.7,2l9.9,13.3l2.7-2L-113.5,22.4z M-128.4,52.9h16.6    v-3.3h-16.6V52.9z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It has the benefit to be lighter, and work with all other StackExchange websites.

To get the icon only, simply remove the first node and adjust viewBox and width:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="38px" viewBox="-135 22 32 38" enable-background="new -135 22 190 38" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <polygon fill="#BCBBBB" points="-108.5,56.2 -108.5,46.3 -105.2,46.3 -105.2,59.5 -135,59.5 -135,46.3 -131.7,46.3 -131.7,56.2       "/>
        <path fill="#F48024" d="M-128,45.4l16.2,3.4l0.7-3.2l-16.2-3.4L-128,45.4z M-125.9,37.6l15,7l1.4-3l-15-7L-125.9,37.6z     M-121.7,30.2l12.7,10.6l2.1-2.5l-12.7-10.6L-121.7,30.2z M-113.5,22.4l-2.7,2l9.9,13.3l2.7-2L-113.5,22.4z M-128.4,52.9h16.6    v-3.3h-16.6V52.9z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your link at the top is broken fyi - it's now part of this image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=8c1c8cba242e